# Substitute string if it isn't in a comment, using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a large file of code that I need to modify and I am using regular expression in Python in order to do so.

One of the modifications I need to do is to identify C++ style inline if/else conditions and simplify them, for instance inside a specific line there could be `...(flag==1 ? 7 : 9)...` and I will simply that directly to `...9...` based on the fact that I know that flag is always 0.
To perform this I use

```
my_code = re.sub(r'\(\s*([^(]+?)\s*\?\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\)', if_else_sub_function, my_code)
```

This scans the entire code and every time the expression is met, that part of the string will be processed by `if_else_sub_function`. This auxiliary function will check if the condition is true and will return the new value for the string.

The substitution logic works very well, but it is unable to understand if `...(flag==1 ? 7 : 9)...` is in a comment or not. Here for example a couple of lines in the code I need to modify:

```
(more text)
// old version was ((coreid==0 ? Ci0:0) << 10)
instr_temp.push_back(LX | ((coreid==0?Ci0:Ci1) << 10));
instr_temp.push_back( LF | (0xb << 6) | (9 << 10) ); // before it was ((flag==1 ? 7 : 9) << 10)
(more text)
```

The regex sub I wrote above would perform the substitution in all the 3 cases in the example, but I would like to limit the match to the only case in which the inline if/else is not part of a comment, and leave the comments untouched. We can assume only `//` comments, no `/*...*/`.

How could I improve the regex string I am using to filter that? I thought of using negative look-ahead and look-behind, but I wasn't able to find a pattern that would work for this case. Also, python look-behind need to have fixed length, otherwise I could have used `(?<!//.*)` at the beginning, but that's not possible.

This is the minimum code needed to reproduce:

```
import re
my_code = """
// old version was ((coreid==0 ? Ci0:0) << 10)
instr_temp.push_back(LX | ((coreid==0?Ci0:Ci1) << 10));
instr_temp.push_back( LF | (0xb << 6) | (9 << 10) ); // before it was ((flag==1 ? 7 : 9) << 10)
"""
my_code = re.sub(r'\(\s*([^(]+?)\s*\?\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\)', "test", my_code)
```

I would like to see "test" substituted only once, in the case where the if/else is not in a comment.
I am okay with substituting "test" with a lambda function if there is no other way.

Comment: My initial reaction here is that you should not be using regex to do this.  Instead, write a parser in Python.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wish I could. This script needs only to "massage" the text to make it compatible for another big tool that unfortunately has a very picky parser. If we owned that tool, I would be able to rewrite the parser, but for now we are stuck with that. The output of my script needs to still be a string with this and many other modifications.

Comment: Pretty difficult if not impossible to do with the limitations imposed, as the solution as is will require manually iterating each line and strip out everything after `//`, apply `re.sub` to the before portions, and then append both before and after portions to the result.  Otherwise if you can use other libraries, the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package supports variable-width look-behind patterns.

Comment: Only if you assume that a single line comment is at the start of a line can you use a regex here. `//` can be part of a string literal, say, some hard-coded URL. Then you risk missing some matches, or overmatch.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good point, however I am sure that the text files I have to modify will not include URLs unless they are in comments, since they are C++ files with low level code.

Comment: Then it's easy, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/fuLqZ4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is a neat solution, because the first literal will consume everything after a comment. I need to think more often of this trick, it seems very powerful. Do you mind adding it as an answer? And how do you think it compares to the solutions I found?

Comment: You may be able to use the following regular expression with Python's regex module: `r'^(?:(?!\/\/).)*\K\(\s*([^(]+?)\s*\?\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\)'`. I tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Y2u2kK/1/) with the PCRE engine. The only thing a bit unusual is `\K` which I know is supported by the regex module. I prepended your regex with `^(?:(?!\/\/).)*\K`. `(?:(?!\/\/).)` consumes characters from the start of the string to where your regex takes over, confirm `//` is not present. `\K` forgets everything matched so far and resets the match to the current location.

Comment: `(?:(?!\/\/).)*` in my last comment is called a [tempered greedy token solution](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed). (I understand that in Python forward slashes need not be escaped.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland if I decide to start using the regex module I may consider that, it's a very interesting solution. I didn't know about `\K`, it sounds very useful. Would it still work if there are more than one ternary operator in the same line of text? Although rare, it's possible. For now I would rather stick with the built-in re module, I don't want to ask all users to install a package, they may not even have pip available on some machines.

Comment: Yes, I believe the regex could be modified to permit multiple matches in one line that are not commented out, but I haven't tested. You could also use the re module to capture the part you want to replace, but I don't think more than one per line. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/9jXL25/2/). It's capture group 1 that would be replaced with the replacement string.

Comment: Note I just replaced my last comment because I updated the link. If you want me to attempt to modify the regex that uses the regex module so that multiple replacements per line could be made, let me know and I'll look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not super satisfied with any of the below solutions, because I don't find them very elegant, but I thought of posting them in case anybody can suggest a way to improve them, or if anybody finds them useful.

One solution is to use a lambda function to skip processing of the match if it is part of a comment:

```
re.sub(r'\(\s*([^(]+?)\s*\?\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\)',
       lambda match: "test"
           if my_code.rfind('\n',0,match.start()) > my_code.rfind('//',0,match.start())
           else match[0],
       my_code)
```

This works by using the start index of the found match `match.start()` and searching for the last occurrence of either a new line or `//` before the match. If `//` is closer to the match than the last new line, then the match is inside a comment and we can skip processing it. This solution is not too bad, I will probably go with this if I can't find anything better.

There is another approach, inspired by @metatoaster 's comment about splitting the lines at `//`, although this does it all at once using regex:

```
re.sub(r'^.*?(?://|$)',
       lambda match: re.sub(r'\(\s*([^(]+?)\s*\?\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\)', "test", match[0]),
       my_code, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

The external `re.sub` will isolate all the lines excluding any comment content, if any. The lambda function will then apply the same logic as in the question, but this time only on relevant code text.
I am not very happy with this approach, because it generates so many more `re.sub` calls (one for each line of text I am processing), while before the external `re.sub` would only match when an inline if/else is found. However I think this is a bit more readable than the other solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `^[^/\r\n]*` wouldn't work because it would stop if it finds the simple division operator, that is just `/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is not true, as you can see from [this example](https://ideone.com/ml9dXx) (I added a division in the middle line). Or am I missing something? In `^.*?(?://|$)` there are explicitly 2 `/`, so it won't match if there is only one

Comment: I did not notice it was a double `/`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a common trick to match and capture a part of a string before matching anything else to be able to restore the captured text in the resulting string via analyzing the match object inside a callable used as the replacement argument:

```
rx = r'(//.*)|\(\s*([^(]+?)\s*\?\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\)'
my_code = re.sub(rx, lambda x: x.group(1) or "test", my_code)
```

The `(//.*)|\(\s*([^(]+?)\s*\?\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\)` regex is your pattern with `(//.*)|` added at the start: it captures `//` and the rest of the line into Group 1. The `lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "test"` replacement takes the match data object (`x`) and if `x.group(1)` matched, `x.group(1)` is returned, else, `test` is used to replace the matched text.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HuzhaT).